# Get data from mysql as array

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for my english..

in mysql has row name iurl.. There is data: 1365269423.jpg,1365270586.jpg,1365270666.jpg,1365270683.jpg

i get its as:

```
<?php $s=mysql_query("select iurl from points where id='".$_GET['id']."' ");

 if($s){

 $array = array();

 while($t=mysql_fetch_array($s)) {  
 $array[] = $t['iurl'];

  }

 print_r($array);
?>
```

it gives me result: `Array ( [0] => 1365269423.jpg,1365270586.jpg,1365270666.jpg,1365270683.jpg )`

And i`m need get it and print like a link

how can i do it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode();` to split the string into an array and then loop over to print each item:

```
$images = explode(",", $t["iurl"]);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$image}\">{$image}</a>";
}
```

Comment: It is already an Array, he gets the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to have result or in your case a .jpg file be the href of your link? If so do this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $t['ur1']?>">......</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you get from your database as you already figured out is an Array
The only thing you need to do is loop trough the array.

ps: consider using mysqli more info at php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

```
<?php 
$s=mysql_query("select iurl from points where id='".$_GET['id']."' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($s)) {
   echo '<a href="'.$row->iurl.'" border="0" title=""><img="http://yourhost.com/images/'.$row->image.' alt=""/></a>'; 
}
?>
```